# OpenGL and GLM: How to send a matrices array to GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have this code:

```
GLuint joint = shader->getUniform("jointTransforms"); //this is always 0
glUniformMatrix4fv(joint, MAX_JOINT_COUNT, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(rotations[0]));
```

And in my shader a uniform array like this:

```
uniform mat4 jointTransforms[MAX_JOINT_COUNT];
```

The problem is, that the shader is not receiving any data at all.
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine:

```
GLuint id_bound_program;

void TextureMgr::bind_program( GLuint id_prog ) { 
    if( id_prog == id_bound_program ) {
        return;
    }

    id_bound_program = id_prog;
    glUseProgram( id_prog );
}

void TextureMgr::update_uniform( GLuint id_program, std::string const & name_uniform, glm::mat4 const & value ) { 
    bind_program( id_program );
    glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( id_program, name_uniform.c_str( ) ), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( value ) );
}
```

Without more information about your program - the contents of shader->getUniform - and the innards of your shader program, I cannot give you a better answer.

Odds are you did not bind your program first.

Comment: The last sentence helped me... I've maybe forgotten to bind it first.. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Cheers!